# Ubuntu: gitweb always looks for projects in /var/cache/git ("404 - no projects found")

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04, gitweb

After installing *gitweb* on an Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) server and changing the variable `$projectroot` in `/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi` to any directory other than `/var/cache/git`, projects are still searched in `/var/cache/git`.

This happens with Ubuntu’s *gitweb* package (1.7.9.5) and also cloning Git’s repository and compiling the latest stable branch (1.8.0.1).

The problem can be also experienced as a "404 - no projects found" on Apache’s gitweb site, because projects would be in a directory different to `/var/cache/git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu the file `/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi` shouldn’t be edited. The `$projectroot` variable should be set in `/etc/gitweb.conf`.

Thanks to the [Git’s mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/210834) for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After defining `$projectroot=/var/git` (as is my case), if I inserted the value of `$projectroot` in the `<title>` in line 3,915, the string `/var/cache/git` was being displayed, so the issue is that somewhere along the cgi file the value of `$projectroot` was reset to the system’s default.

The culprit of this behaviour lies in the `git_get_projects_list` subroutine where, in line 2,865, the global variable `our $projectroot` is defined once again, resetting its value to the system’s default. The way to solve it is, on that same line, to declare it and set it to the same value as above:

```
...
2,863. # global variables                                       
2,864. our $project_maxdepth = 2007;
2,865. our $projectroot = "/var/git";
2,866. # skip project-list toplevel, if we get it.              
2,867. return if (m!^[/.]$!);
...
```

I haven’t seen this issue reported in Ubuntu’s or Git’s mailing lists, so any insight as if this is a bug or a feature (it looks clearly as a bug to me, though), or if this happens in other Linux distributions, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was misguided by the [Git book’s ‘4.6 Git on the Server - GitWeb’](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb), as Ubuntu’s setup is configured in `/etc/gitweb.conf`. I’ve added a second answer with the “good” solution.